# Is Predator ever called Predator in any of the films?

Tags: alien-vs.-predator, predator, predator-series

Just because out of universe, we call it Predator, I know that doesn't mean it's actual title or name in universe is Predator.

But do we ever hear anyone in any of the *Predator* or *AVP* movies refer to Predator as Predator or even the/a predator?

I don't remember ever having a [scene like this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=F8mYLi3PGOc) while I was watching any of the Predator movies.

Comment: It might be referred to as a *predator* (lowercase) but not as a *Predator* (name of species)...

Comment: @Paulie_D For all we know that's all the movies *ever* did. They're just written with a capital P because they're movie titles. But those were likely *never* naming a species rather than a, well, alien predator. It just evolved into the denotion of a specific thing, because that's what viewers like to make of it. Pretty much the same how the inappropriately specific use of the word xenomorph came around.

Comment: @TARS the script of Predator 2 refers to it as "the Predator" (proper noun).

Comment: I could have sworn the original movie had Arnold's character (after besting the Predator) asking "What the hell are you?" and the response being a near-unintelligible "I am Predator", but the official script disagrees with my memory and I can't really understand what the alien is saying when I re-watch it, even while following along with the script. The script says that the Predator simply repeats Arnold's question, improving its pronunciation with each word, but that's not even close to what I see in the movie.

Comment: [Are the Predator's last words to Dutch a mimic or a question?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/145743/are-the-predators-last-words-to-dutch-a-mimic-or-a-question) @DeepDeadpool - *improvising* its pronunciation, IMO.

Comment: In other media, the creatures are referred to as *Yautja* and (I think) *Hish*. Not sure if these names are canon.

Comment: I think ironically, that the Alien is called a Predator in one of the films, and that the Predator is called an Alien in one of the films. This is unrelated to what you asked, but it was my first thought for some strange reason.

Answer (score 73, accepted):

The only time it's said in any of the films is in **Predators (2010)** Isabelle [says](https://www.avpgalaxy.net/files/scripts/script-predators-finch-litvak.pdf):

> It’s because we are predators,
>   Royce. Just like them.

Here's it's not used as a proper noun.

***There's no in-universe use of it as a proper noun.***

In the script for **Predator 2 (1990)** it is [referred to](https://www.avpgalaxy.net/files/scripts/predator-2-1989-12-15.pdf) as the Predator.

> his vision STEPS IN, downward, through the canyons of steel, the distorted WHINE of a SIREN, growing louder as **the
>   Predator's** vision ZOOMS IN to the streets below, coming to
>   rest on a bizarre scene

However it is never referred to as such by any characters.

Comment: I was going to say this answer is moot given that it's not naming them Predator, but looks like the question allows both, nice job!

Answer (score 7):

From the new movie "The Predator":

> Merc Soldier: Why do you call it the Predator?
>
> Traeger: It's a nickname, the data suggests that it tracks its prey, exploits weakness. Seems to enjoy it, like a game.
>
> Merc Soldier: That's not a predator, that's a sports hunter. A predator kills its prey to survive, what you're describing is more like a bass fisherman.
>
> Traeger: Well we took a vote, Predator is cooler. Right? Fuck yeah.

Source: [IMDB - "The Predator" (2018) Quotes](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt3829266/quotes/qt4151105)

Comment: I want to downvote the movie, but it's not letting me...

Comment: I hope they call the next movie _THE BASS FISHERMAN_

Answer (score 1):

Yes. In *Predator 2*, Gary Busey, when explaining to Danny Glover that it’s an alien, calls it a predator.

> KEYES: It's taken us over two weeks to learn his patterns. He comes here every two days to feed. Seems he has a taste for beef.
>
> HARRIGAN: I didn't think he was vegetarian.
>
> KEYES: **Well, we've prepared a little trap for this predator.**

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F!  Can you find an exact quote from a script or a clip on Youtube?  I don't remember that, and nobody else has noticed it.

Comment: @DavidW - It's at 01:07:59 in the subtitles

Comment: I’m not sure how to post an image but it seems you found it already!